# Android Wear- Getting Data from WearableListenerService

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android wear app that receives data from the mobile device app every x seconds.
For receiving the data, I'm using the MessageApi:

Listener in the wearable app:

```
public class MWearableListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    private String m_lastMessage;    

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);

        m_lastMessage = new String(messageEvent.getData());
    }
}
```

I would like my wearable app UI to access the data.
I know I can use the GoogleApiClient to send data locally but I would rather avoid that.

What's the best practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in docs, you have 2 approaches:
MessageApi.MessageListener via listner in your activity or WearableListenerService.

> Applications expecting to be notified of events while in the
>   background should extend this class. Activities and other short-lived
>   Android components may use addListener(GoogleApiClient,
>   DataApi.DataListener), addListener(GoogleApiClient,
>   MessageApi.MessageListener) and addListener(GoogleApiClient,
>   NodeApi.NodeListener) to receive events for a limited period of time.

this is the key difference. So you should decide what is your case and chose proper api.